# Does this procedure always generates at least one prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures

Suppose that $p_n$ is the $n$-th prime and $n \neq 1,2$.

To every $p_n$ we can associate $(n-2)$-tuple $(2p_n+p_{n-1},...,2p_n+p_2)$ and  from some calculations that I have done it seems that it *could be* that at least one of the numbers from that $(n-2)$-tuple for every $p_n$ is a prime number.

Is that true?

Comment: @DietrichBurde That result shows that there is some prime in that interval, but are you sure that it is of one of those $(n-2)$-forms? These $(n-2)$ numbers are generated in somehow special way.

Comment: @DietrichBurde This procedure generates discrete numbers - not an interval. So it seems like that argument is invalid.

Comment: I would tend to think that the answer is yes, but your are right. This is not clear from this estimate. It *could be* that this is an unsolved problem. Then you cannot expect too many useful answers. By the way, I meant the  interval $[2p_n,3p_n] \cap \Bbb Z$, containing only finitely many numbers.

Comment: @jwc845 Yes, it is not valid argument, other approaches are needed.

Comment: Looks like your question is a more specific version of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture If Goldbach's Conjecture holds true then so does yours. If Goldbach's holds false then yours may be false or true.

Comment: if $p_n$ is 1 mod 6, then you only have to check 5 mod 6 or 3, for 5 mod 6, you only have to check 1 mod 6, or 3.

Answer (score 1):

If this conjecture were true then it would show that every even number of the form twice a prime is the difference of two primes.

I believe this is an open question for even numbers in general and so (although it looks highly likely) it is  not likely to have an elementary solution.

Comment: I think that it should be easier to establish this for even numbers that are twice a prime than for all the even numbers, since we are dealing here with "very small" subset of the set of even numbers.

Comment: I hope you are right. However, whatever way being twice a prime affects  the conjecture is, in itself, unlikely to be elementary.