# Is the set of primes which can be represented as sum of different primes infinite?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Although everything is clear from a title of a question I will just add some notation and two simple examples.

If we denote the set of all primes which are sum of different primes as $P$ then, for example $29 \in P$ since $29=2+3+11+13$ but $11 \notin P$ since $11=2+2+7$ and $11=3+3+5$.

Is $P$ an infinite set?

**Edit**: As mentioned in the comments, if the twin-primes conjecture is true then also this question is answered in the affirmative but I firmly believe that this can be solved without first solving twin-primes conjecture because this is much weaker than twin-primes conjecture since here there are no restrictions on the number of summands, which equals two in the twin-prime conjecture.

Comment: If the twin prime conjecture were true, then yes, as the older sibling in each twinprime pair would be in your set.

Comment: @JMoravitz This could be solved without twin-prime conjecture? I think we do not need that conjecture here.

Comment: *It could*, similarly to your [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3402845/does-this-procedure-always-generates-at-least-one-prime).

Comment: @DietrichBurde But as I study some materials I arrive at those questions, is it wrong to ask them here?

Comment: @DietrichBurde how could it?
To me this looks like it is equivalent to the twin prime conjecture (if we restrict ourselves to positive primes), since $p+q\equiv 0\mod 2$ if $p\neq 2$ and $q\neq 2$.

Comment: goldbach's weak conjecture states all odd numbers greater than 9 are the sum of three primes.

Comment: @PinkPanther The twin prime conjecture is equivalent to there being infinitely many primes expressible as the sum of **two** primes. The question doesn't restrict to sums of two primes, however. So, if the twin prime conjecture is true, then a much stronger version of this statement is true.

Comment: @TheoBendit Yes, the twin-prime conjecture is much stronger than this, in this question there are no restrictions on the number of summands.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think that of the 7 questions I have asked 4 are answered without any need to mention unsolved conjectures, and of those 3 that are left I think that exactly this one is within reach. But I understand, I ask too much.

Comment: It is not necessarily "too much". It could be more detailed and interesting. For example, you could focus perhaps on a question which seems to be in reach and then think about ways of proving it.After this, your next question could be much more specific.

Comment: @DietrichBurde That seems right, thanks for the friendly advice, it is a good one.

Comment: This follows immediately from [this stronger result](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1382663/462). There is no need to invoke versions of the twin prime conjecture: Bertrand's postulate suffices.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I looked at that post and it seems all there very much relies on induction, do you know how to avoid induction in those proofs?

Comment: Almost nothing about the integers can be established without induction.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in fact something stronger holds: Every integer $n\ge12$ can be written as a nontrivial sum of distinct primes (*nontrivial* means here that at least 2 summands are involved).

This holds unconditionally (i.e., it is not dependent on the twin prime conjecture or any of its variants), and follows easily from Bertrand's postulate. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1382840/462) for details.

It would be nice to strengthen the above so that there is an absolute bound on the number of required summands. But such a thing seems very close now to the twin prime conjecture itself.

Comment: The link you provide shows that every integer $n \ge 7$ can be written as a sum of distinct primes. However, it does not state the sum can always be *nontrivial*, i.e., that it involves at least $2$ summands as you describe. For example, as the OP stated in the question, and the link example shows, $11 = 11$, with there not being any way to have $11$ be the sum of $2$ or more distinct primes.

Comment: Ah, you are right. It should be $n\ge12$. The largest prime used in the decomposition is at most $\max(11,n-7)$, so the decomposition is nontrivial for $n>11$.

Answer (score 0):

Probably.

As several commenters have noted, the result would follow from the twin prime conjecture.

Improvements to the bound in Zhang's prime gap theorem say that there are infinitely many pairs of primes separated by at most $246$.

Unfortunately, you can't express all the positive integers less than $246$ as a sum of distinct primes. But there may be a way to use this bound to reduce the problem to a doable finite computation.

http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=Bounded_gaps_between_primes